# Replace part with sql only

Tags: sql

I have a big list of images in my database.

the images are all jpg now.

They used to be jpg and png so i saved the extension in my database.

Now i want to delete all the extensons so everything after the dot (including the dot).

Is this possible with sql.

I think i should use something like :

```
update Where row like '%.jpg' or '%.JPG' or '%.png' or '%.PNG' set value row ..
```

but i cant find anything. is this possible with sql?

I know i can do it with php, with explode  and then just echo part[0] but i want to change it in my database so everyting looks alot neater.

Comment: What database are you using?  The answer is yes, but the details depends on the database

Comment: i dont know what you mean the name of the database? i connect with mysql workbench.

Comment: If you have a lot of records, I'd back up your database before you do this.  In case you perform the concatenation and the code doesn't do what you were expecting it to.

Comment: If you connect with MySQL workbench, your database is MySQL.  Other names for this are database engine and Relational Database Management System, or RDBMS for short.  If you want to make it easier for people to answer your questions, this information is important.  Simply tagging your question with sql is too vague.  sql is a language used by many database engines.

Comment: @DanBracuk Thanks i will add it the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  The syntax is:

```
update <table>
    set value = substring_index(row, '.', 1)
    Where row like '%.jpg' or row like '%.JPG' or row like '%.png' or row like '%.PNG'
```

This assumes there is only one `'.'` in the name.

EDIT:

If `.` can appear in the name more than once, you can use this trick:

```
update <table>
    set value = substring_index(row, '.',
                                length(row) - length(replace(row, '.', ''))
                               )
    Where row like '%.jpg' or row like '%.JPG' or row like '%.png' or row like '%.PNG'
```

The expression `length(row) - length(replace(row, '.', '')` counts the number of periods in the row.

You can also express the `where` as:

```
    where substring_index(row, '.', -1) in ('jpg', 'JPG', 'png', 'PNG')
```

Comment: It only took the first or statements changed it after the first run to the png or statements and it worked perfectly

Comment: @SvenB . . . You can do it with the `or`, you just have to repeat the `like` comparison for each one.  I missed that syntax issue at first.